# VBA to copy values from specific range in many worksheets of source workbook to same range in many worksheets of destination workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm editing this post to provide more detail.

This is an attempt to copy values from a specific range in many worksheets (about 90) in a source workbook to the same specific range in many worksheets in a destination workbook. The worksheets in both source and destination workbooks have the same names.

For example, for worksheets with names "A" through "N", algorithm might be something like:

```
Copy from SourceWorkbook.Worksheet("A").Range ("H46:H85")
PasteValues to DestinationWorkbook.Worksheet("A").Range ("H46:H85")
.
.
.
Copy from SourceWorkbook.Worksheet("N").Range ("H46:H85")
PasteValues to DestinationWorkbook.Worksheet("N").Range ("H46:H85")
```

An error is occurring when I try to only allow pasting to occur if destination ws name is same as source ws name.

This is what I have so far.

```
Sub TestGetReview_5()

'still not working

Dim ToWb As Workbook
Dim FromWb As Workbook

Dim FromSht As Worksheet
Dim ToSht As Worksheet
Dim SheetName As String 'not sure this is needed

Set FromWb = Workbooks("SourceWorkbook.xlsm") 'wb is open  
Set ToWb = Workbooks("DestinationWorkbook.xlsm")  'wb is open  

For Each FromSht In FromWb.Worksheets
If FromSht.Name Like "N*" And FromSht.Name <> "Notes" Then

SheetName = FromSht.Name
FromWb.Activate
FromSht.Activate
Range("H46:H85").Copy
ToWb.Activate
Set ToWb.ToSht.Sheets(SheetName) = FromWb.FromSht.Sheets(SheetName)  'Attempt to only allow pasting if Destination worksheet name is same as source worksheet name produces error "object doesn't support this property or method". Variable SheetName is correctly set to first ws in source wb
ToSht.Activate
Range("H46:H85").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End If
Next FromSht

End Sub
```

I really appreciate the assistance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please keep in mind that StackOverflow is not the right place to ask people to write code for you. If you have a specific issue while writing/running your code, that question would be a better fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: You can delete your own question, by clicking on the delete link unde the question.

Comment: Thanks, Zev. I'll post my version with more detail. Thought I had it working but alas, not yet.

Comment: This has now become a different (albeit slightly better) question. The appropriate thing to do would be to notify the other answerers that this is the case, via comments on their answers.

Comment: Also, if you want another user to be notified about a comment you have written, write the user's name -- e.g. `@ZevSpitz` somewhere in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate cause of the error is that `FromWb` refers to a [`Workbook`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835568.aspx) object, which represents an Excel workbook. `Workbook` objects don't have any properties or methods named `FromSht`, so this expression fails:

```
    FromWb.FromSht
```

---

You seem to be misusing the [`Set`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251642.aspx) statement, which:

> Assigns an object reference to a variable or property.

It doesn't enforce any sort of equality, or similarity of names. For that, you have to make some kind of comparison:

```
If FromSht.Name = ToSht.Name Then
    'do something here
End If
```

---

If `Option Explicit` doesn't appear at the top of your module, then it should.

[`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278855.aspx) forces you to declare variables before using them, and helps catch misspellings and otherwise misdeclared variables.

---

If we try to access a non-existent worksheet, we'll just get an error. In order to simplify things, we can write a function that takes a workbook and a name, and if we can successfully get to the worksheet by that name, return that worksheet. Otherwise, the function will return `Nothing`, which means it doesn't refer to any worksheet.

```
Function SafeGetWorksheet(book As Workbook, name As String) As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Set SafeGetWorksheet = book.Sheets(name)
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
End Function
```

Then, the code can be written like this:

```
Dim source As Workbook
Set source = Workbooks("SourceWorkbook.xlsm") 'wb is open

Dim destination As Workbook
Set destination = Workbooks("DestinationWorkbook.xlsm")  'wb is open

Dim sheet As Worksheet
'The following For Each will iterate through all the sheets in the source workbook
'You may want to limit the source sheets somehow, as in S.Meaden's answer
For Each sheet In source.Sheets 
    Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
    Set destinationSheet = SafeGetWorksheet(destination,sheet.Name)

    'If there is a worksheet with the same name in the destination
    If Not destinationSheet Is Nothing Then
        'copy the cells from the source sheet's range to the destination sheet's range
        destinationSheet.Range("H46:H85").Value = sheet.Range("H46:H85").Value
    End If
Next
```

---

[VBA References](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264383.aspx):

- [`Set` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251642.aspx)
- [`If..Then`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251599.aspx)
- [`Option Explicit` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278855.aspx)
- [`On Error` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251688.aspx)
- [`For Each` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264596.aspx)

[Excel object model reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee861528.aspx):

- [`Workbook` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835568.aspx)
- [`Worksheet` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx)
- [Returning an object from a collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841122.aspx)

Comment: Method 1 wouldn't be accepted because this routine is part of a larger process to combine distinct copied ranges from several source workbooks into the same worksheets of the destination workbook. Each range from the source workbook is distinct. I added some detail to my problem definition at the top of this page that will hopefully make this more clear. Thanks so much for looking at this, Zev. I am not familiar with the use of a Connection Object but will look into it. As you can surely see, I am fairly new to working with VB!

Comment: @user7354053 I've rewritten my answer.

Comment: That totally rocks! This solves my problem and I learned a few things about both VBA and using this website. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need a magic line of code using the .Value2 both as a bulk getter and setter.

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim lLoop As Long
    For lLoop = Asc("A") To Asc("N")
        DestinationWorkbook.Worksheet(Chr(lLoop)).Range("H46:H85").Value2 = SourceWorkbook.Worksheet(Chr(lLoop)).Range("H46:H85").Value2
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why use `.Value2` instead of `.Value`? Only makes a difference if you are using dates, and in that case, usually `.Value` works better for copying values.

Comment: @vacip: fine.  habit I suppose.

Comment: This is throwing an error "Object doesn't support this property or method" when it get to the line "DestinationWorkbook...." I tried a couple variations but couldn't get it to run. I added some detail to the original problem description at the top of this page that hopefully adds clarity. Thank you so much for looking into this, S Meaden!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to copy from each row on one sheet and paste into the same row on another sheet, right.

```
For Each Cell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J1:J" & LastRow1)
    If Cell.Value = "x" Or Cell.Value = "X" Then
        matchRow = Cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    End If
Next
```

I'm assuming there is a 'X' in ColumnJ, and this is the criteria, or flag, that says you need to do the copy/paste.

Comment: Both row and column of source and destination are the same. However, the destination sheet is in another workbook and the copy paste routine should only occur if the destination sheet has the same name as the source sheet. I expanded my problem description above to make this more clear. Thank you so much for your efforts on this!